# $this->user->hasPermission('access','catalog/product') not working

Tags: permissions, opencart

I want to hide the menu option from admin menu according to current user login. I have tried the following code:

```
$this->user->hasPermission('access','catalog/product');
```

but it is not working. How should this be done?

Comment: How much type of users group you have ? which user group hide which acress .? You can do it from admin side configuration there are no need to do changes in code.

Comment: i got the problem. misspelled the controller name. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can hide the acccess of admin side by making user group. Go to

```
System-> User-> User group
```

then add a new gropu here & assign access role that you wants to access this kind of users. Going to attach an image here

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i got the problem. misspelled the controller name. thanks